# How to Disable Multiple Child Process in Node JS/ Node Webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

Im new to Node js and node webkit and I tried searching for disabling multiple child processes but unfortunately I wasn't able to find any.

```
function myFunction()
{

    const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
    const child = execFile("notepad.exe", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    });
}
```

here is a sample code that I want to disable multiple **notepad.exe** and run only 1 instance of it only..

Thanks

Comment: no idea this will work for you...but,in think you should define a for loop and in for loop define a function where you can add the child process to the list for tracking and listen to the response or errors

Comment: alright ill try that.